What's left unaccounted by /proc/meminfo
What is the proper formula to understand distribution of MemTotal - MemFree?
On a system where Huge pages are almost not utilized I assume that it should be the sum of the following stats:

page cache ('Buffers', 'Cached', 'SwapCached')
kernel memory ('VmallocUsed', 'Slab', 'PageTables', 'KernelStack')
user-space allocated memory ('AnonPages')

On my system:
MemTotal - MemFree = 3970852 
Buffers + Cached + SwapCached + VmallocUsed + Slab + PageTables + KernelStack + AnonPages = 1747364
Why the difference is so huge?
Is it possible that something is not included in meminfo stats?
As per stated here:

The memory reported by the non overlapping counters may not
add up to the overall memory usage and the difference for some workloads
can be substantial.

Full meminfo:
MemTotal             4040824
MemFree                69972
MemAvailable          116364
Buffers                35720
Cached                118712
SwapCached             67364
Active                625652
Inactive              827128
Active(anon)          566120
Inactive(anon)        757488
Active(file)           59532
Inactive(file)         69640
Unevictable             1396
Mlocked                 1396
SwapTotal            7340028
SwapFree             5805036
Dirty                    256
Writeback                136
AnonPages            1280096
Mapped                 86192
Shmem                  23924
Slab                  219608
SReclaimable           89480
SUnreclaim            130128
KernelStack            12096
PageTables             13768
NFS_Unstable               0
Bounce                     0
WritebackTmp               0
CommitLimit          9360440
Committed_AS         6649808
VmallocTotal       263061440
VmallocUsed                0
VmallocChunk               0
Percpu                  2144
AnonHugePages           2048
ShmemHugePages             0
ShmemPmdMapped             0
HugePages_Total            0
HugePages_Free             0
HugePages_Rsvd             0
HugePages_Surp             0
Hugepagesize            2048
Hugetlb                    0


Memory consumption/release happens on the nanosecond scale. Any snapshot of memory usage will be inaccurate,  and should be used only for general info and anomaly detection

The problem is that I observed such a situation for about 10h
